# VBA To Extract HTML CDATA

Tags: javascript, xml, excel, vba

I am trying to use Excel VBA to copy the URL content in between the CData nodes from a list of websites with the same html format. The HTML sample is here:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
Wistia.iframeInit({"assets":[{"type":"original","slug":"original","display_name":
"Original file","ext":"mp4","size":2,"bitrate":2677,"public":true,
"url":"https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/1.bin"},
{"type":"original","slug":"original","display_name":"Original file",
"ext":"mp4","size":1,"bitrate":2677,"public":true,
"url":"https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/2.bin"},
//]]>
</script>
```

I am unable to extract the CDATA information with excel VBA alone it seems. Each time I use the following script below, I obtain either blank or "[object HTMLScriptElement]"

```
Sub test()

Dim ie As Object
Dim html As Object
Dim mylinks As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim myURL As String
Dim erow As Long

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRow
myURL = Sheet1.Cells(i, "A").Value
ie.navigate myURL
ie.Visible = False

While ie.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend

Set html = ie.document
Set mylinks = html.getElementsByName("script")(1).innerText

For Each link In mylinks
erow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(erow, 1).Value = link
Cells(erow, 1).Columns.AutoFit
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I gather by its absence that the URL is proprietary, private or both. All I receive is `A route to "GET /" does not exist....`.

Comment: link: view-source:https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6w.



I cleaned it up to truncate it for pasting purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my experiences, automating the Internet Explorer is highly unstable. So I would use XMLHTTP as long as possible. Of course your HTML tag soup is not XML and cannot be parsed as such. But we can at least get the responseText with XMLHTTP and then using text methods further.

Example:

```
Sub test()
 sURL = "https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/vud7ff4i6w"

 Dim oXMLHTTP As Object
 Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", sURL, False
 oXMLHTTP.Send

 sResponseText = oXMLHTTP.responseText

 aScriptParts = Split(sResponseText, "<script", , vbTextCompare) 'separate in parts delimited with <script
 For i = LBound(aScriptParts) + 1 To UBound(aScriptParts) 'lbound+1 because the first part should not be script. It is the body html.
  sScriptPart = Split(aScriptParts(i), "</script", , vbTextCompare)(0) 'only the part before </script belongs to the script
  MsgBox sScriptPart
 Next
End Sub
```

You could also use regular expressions instead of the `Split` approach to separate the script parts from the whole text. But this you should ask the `RegEx` specialists with a separate question then. I'm not such a `RegEx` specialist.

Comment: Axel - this is great, I'm confused about why you put in the (0) in the bellow code:
    sScriptPart = Split(aScriptParts(i), "</script", , vbTextCompare)(0)

Comment: `Split` gets an array of parts from the given string splitted by the delimiter. In this case the delimiter is "</script". So only the first part - the first array element - is before the "</split" and belongs to the script element. The `arrayobject(0)` gets only this first array element.